# How to uninstall X server and related applications?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a partner who keeps installing X, a VNC server, Firefox, Thunderbird, etc. on our web server. I’ve been trying to explain to him that that’s not how we are to use the web server—we’re to use SSH instead. Unfortunately, I can’t find a way to uninstall *all* of the packages that he has manually installed.

We have Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and I’m trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS but we don’t have enough space on the VPS. I’m sure that removing these packages will clear up enough space.

Comment: Run this command as root: `find / -type f -ls | sort -r -n -k7 | head -n 20`. it will list the largest 20 files on the server. may be of some help

Comment: Is he installing the software with package manager or compiling from the source? In the first case, just take a look at /var/log/dpkg.log and /var/log/apt/ and you should be able to work out what he installed from the time and dates.

Comment: He did an a few installations using apt-get and the rest of them through Ubuntu Software Center.